# How to apply TLS session tickets from a previous TLS session to a new connecton in OpenSSL?

Tags: ssl, openssl

I'm working on improving TLS support for my network library. I want to support TLS session tickets on the client side in order to reduce the latency. I've read the documents and find that I can access the ticket (if peer supports it) using `SSL_SESSION_get0_ticket` and it's expire time with `SSL_SESSION_get_ticket_lifetime_hint`. However, I can't find an API to apply a ticket to a new connection.

So far I tried creating a new session using `d2i_SSL_SESSION` and that causes the handshake to hang. While using `SSL_set_session_ticket_ext` causes the handshake to fail. The following are pseudo code to illustrate what I did.

```c
SSL* ssl = get_my_ssl_connection();
SSL_SESSION* session = SSL_get_session(ssl);

unsigned int ticketLifetimeSec;
const unsigned char* ticketPtr;
size_t ticketLen = 0;
if(SSL_SESSION_has_ticket(session)) {
    ticketLifetimeSec = SSL_SESSION_get_ticket_lifetime_hint(session);
    SSL_SESSION_get0_ticket(session, &ticketPtr, &ticketLen);
}
else {
  /* error handle */
}


SSL* ssl2 = SSL_new(ctx);
// SSL_set_session_ticket_ext(ssl2, ticketPtr, ticketLen); // causes handshake to fail

// Causes handshake to hang. OpenSSL is waiting for more data then the server sends back
// SSL_SESSION *session = d2i_SSL_SESSION(NULL, ticketPtr, ticketLen);
// SSL_set_session(ssl2, session);
// SSL_SESSION_free(session);

SSL_set_accept_state(ssl2);
do_handskae(); // this is broken by applying tickets
```

How could I use tickets to reduce latency? I have looked through the OpenSSL API and can't find other potential solutions. Am I going into a completely incorrect direction?

Comment: I'm wondering if session resumption is not automatically enabled if the server indicates support for it. The `SSL_SESSION_get0_ticket` mainly seems in place for a callback handler *for the server*. Have you tried to analyze the traffic?

Comment: In short: the point is to use SSL_get_session to get the session and SSL_set_session to apply it to a newly created SSL object before doing the SSL handshake. No need to explicitly handle tickets.